# Debugging Flash on a webserver in FlashDevelop

Tags: flash, haxe, flashdevelop

I have attempted to set
`Project Settings > Output > Test Project > Webserver...` to the path of the index.html embedded with my SWF file. Or even `Open Document...`. It opens a tab but cannot debug.

Another thing I have tried is `Debug > Start Remove Session` but nothing happens.

Comment: What does the output panel say?

Comment: After building successful, it says:  
`Web Server starting with root: D:\path\to\project\bin\
Running process: http://localhost:2000/index.html`
btw, it's a munit test project